# warning: variable ‘{variable}’ set but not used - C++

Tags: c++

Hm, it's complaining that these variables are declared but unused.  They certainly are used.  What could be the cause?

```
recorders/r5000/r5000.c: In function ‘r5000_locate_device’:
recorders/r5000/r5000.c:201:9: warning: variable ‘open_status’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int open_status = usb_set_configuration(device_handle,1);
     ^
recorders/r5000/r5000.c: In function ‘r5000_start_stream’:
recorders/r5000/r5000.c:258:7: warning: variable ‘bytes’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
int bytes;
   ^
recorders/r5000/r5000.c: In function ‘r5000_get_power_state’:
recorders/r5000/r5000.c:551:7: warning: variable ‘len’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   int len;
   ^
recorders/r5000/r5k_sat.c: In function ‘sat_read_pmt_pkt’:
recorders/r5000/r5k_sat.c:120:17: warning: variable ‘last_sec’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
int sid, sec, last_sec, pcrpid, epid, type;
             ^
recorders/r5000/r5k_sat.c:120:12: warning: variable ‘sec’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
int sid, sec, last_sec, pcrpid, epid, type;
```

I tried to include r5000.c here, but the forum wouldn't let me. ("too much code")  So it's here:  https://pastee.org/mu3y9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at only `open_status`, the warnings are correct:

```
  if (device_handle) {
    int open_status = usb_set_configuration(device_handle,1);

    open_status = usb_claim_interface(device_handle,0);

    open_status = usb_set_altinterface(device_handle,0);
  }
```

It is only being assigned to, not used.

Comment: Oh dear.  I only commented out int.  I'll try all of it.